# site - is currently unable to handle this request Http error 500

Tags: magento, server, internal-server-error

once i clicked on "Proceed to checkout" button, we are getting below error

**The sitename.com is't working 

www.sitename.co.nz is currently unable to handle this request 

Http Error 500**

even in backend when we open some orders, than also same error in order-view page.

we have shared hosting.

Comment: 500 errors indicate the server process has terminated because of an application error. Check your web server error logs for the entries to help troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with magento core file cc.php file , one of our devoloper edited it in wrong way, once i replaced the
original file, it worked fine.